# Cannot implement overload for + in Rust due to type restrictions

Tags: generics, rust, operator-overloading

I am trying to create a method that allows summing 2 point types that I have defined that can have any integer or float value (defined as a generic). The implementation of the struct is:

```
pub struct Point<T: PointTypeTrait>{
    x: T,
    y: T
}
```

The trait that restricts the type that the values can take is:

```
pub trait PointTypeTrait{}
impl PointTypeTrait for i8{}
impl PointTypeTrait for i16{}
impl PointTypeTrait for i32{}
impl PointTypeTrait for i64{}
impl PointTypeTrait for i128{}
impl PointTypeTrait for f32{}
impl PointTypeTrait for f64{}
```

When I try to implement the Add for Point method to overload the + operator I proceed by writing the following code:

```
impl<T: PointTypeTrait> Add for Point<T> {
    type Output = Point<T>;

    fn add(self, other: Point<T>) -> Self::Output {
        Point::new_point(
            self.x + other.x,
            self.y + other.y)
    }
}
```

When I try to compile I obtain the following error:

```
error[E0369]: cannot add `T` to `T`
  --> src/point.rs:34:20
   |
34 |             self.x + other.x,
   |             ------ ^ ------- T
   |             |
   |             T
   |
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
29 | impl<T: PointTypeTrait + std::ops::Add<Output = T>> Add for Point<T> {
   |                        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Does anyone knows a solution or a way to allow this?

Comment: Have you tried adding `+ std::ops::Add<Output = T>` as the compiler suggests?

Comment: I honestly did not understand the compiler message completely (today is my first-day programming in Rust) @cafce25 does the addition keep the restrictions that I impose in the Trait?

Comment: It says that you only implement `Add` for `Point<T>` if `T` also implements `Add`. Alternatively you could change PointTypeTrait to `pub trait PointTypeTrait : Add<Output=Self> + Sized {}` to ensure that you can only create Points that can be added.

Comment: congratz on your first day, leçon of the day, read advice of compiler :p